# mysql How can i compare two rows in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I'm sorry if I'm repeating that question, but, I haven't found anything that could help me.

Anyway, that's the question:

I'm writing an dating aplication, in this app, I'm bugging in the part of mutual interest.

I mean, you'll have 3 options about a person (do you wanna date with him/her? Yes, maybe, no).

So, I've create a table, that saves your userId, the persons'id that you wanna date, and your response (yes, no or maybe).

Is there a way to compare if you said yes or maybe, and the other person says yes or maybe, will return something like a mutual person?

something like (if you said yes or no, and the person said yes or no then select all mutual persons).

I'm sorry if sounds confuse, but in case of doubt, I can explain better.

My English doesn't help, though.... I'm Brazilian

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: Please include your table schemas.

Comment: Perhaps the MINUS operator... `Select A,B,C from tableName where uniqueKey = 1 MINUS Select A,B,C from tableName where UniqueKey = 2`  Boa Sorte!

Comment: Probably `INNER JOIN` could help you. But we need some code or DB schema to help you

Comment: Yeh - you could do a self join

Answer (score 6):

Something like this,

```
SELECT  LEAST(a.UserID, a.PersonID) AS Person1,
        GREATEST(a.UserID, a.PersonID) AS Person2,
        a.Response
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN TableName b
            ON  a.UserID = b.PersonID AND
                a.PersonID = b.UserID AND
                a.Response = b.Response
GROUP   BY Person1, Person2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddd6e/2)

Assuming you have records like this,

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ USERID ║ PERSONID ║ RESPONSE ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║        2 ║ yes      ║
║      2 ║        1 ║ yes      ║
║      3 ║        4 ║ no       ║
║      4 ║        3 ║ yes      ║
║      5 ║        6 ║ maybe    ║
║      6 ║        5 ║ maybe    ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

The OUTPUT of the query is

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ PERSON1 ║ PERSON2 ║ RESPONSE ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║       2 ║ yes      ║
║       5 ║       6 ║ maybe    ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: very nice, but, How could I return an especific user? I mean, in the client dashboard must print the values where HE is the person ID.

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much. According to your answers, I've reached this:

```
SELECT p2.atirador AS mutual
FROM paqueras AS p1, paqueras AS p2
WHERE p2.alvo = $UserID
AND p1.atirador = $UserID
AND p2.atirador = p1.alvo
AND (
p1.resposta1 =  "sim"
OR p1.resposta1 =  "talvez"
)
AND (
p2.resposta1 =  "sim"
OR p2.resposta1 =  "talvez"
)
```

What I've did? I'll try explain, I'm getting all the person that is mutual with the user ID. That'll come handy when the user access his mutual page, you know?

Well, so far so good... thank you guys, I'll report any bug. But let's hope not ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT him.id as "him",  
her.id AS "her",  
FROM match him, match her  
WHERE him.id = her.id OR her.id=him.id;
```

You can extent out as required... to match on the yes / no / maybe field.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
SELECT * FROM test t1 INNER JOIN test t2 ON t1.id = t2.personid AND t2.id=t1.personid WHERE t1.response=t2.response;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9170c/1

If you want the results for a specific response (Yes, May be), you can add that in the `WHERE` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Select Userid As p1, Personid p2
From YourTable
Where (Response like "Yes" OR Response like "Maybe") AND p2 IN(
Select Userid
From YourTable
Where Userid = p2 AND Personid = p1 AND (Response like "Yes" OR Response like "Maybe");
```